# Create a multicast router

Tags: network-programming, video-streaming, vlc, multicast

How can i make my laptop to act as a multicast router. 
I need to stream video content to other computers with in same network. How can i make my laptop to work as a multicast router.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools like that [iou](http://evilrouters.net/2011/01/18/cisco-iou-faq/),[iou2net.pl](http://inetpro.org/wiki/Connect_IOU_with_real_networks_or_dynamips)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple - write a simple app to recieve multicast on one network card and simply re-send it on another one. One packet in - one packet out. And this way you can make userspace multicast router. Very easy. Just dont forget to register IGMP on these sockets.
This way you can also send it to multiple networks at once, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Say you install Cisco IOU on a VM (ubuntu) or directly if you already use ubuntu.
Every instance you run (level 3 bin files for routers and level 2 for switches) is dealt with as a seperate physical machine.
This way you can:

- create a network within one machine.
- save up on memory as IOUs don't really take that much (64mb by default)
- do any type of testing you need locally and for free.

iou2net.pl for instance is a tool you use to link an IOU instance to external networks.
This way you can use a real router/switch or network setting up the IOU either as one or a group or client OR your server itself.